# IIS Express gets loaded and unloaded DLLs

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

My Asp.Net MVC project was working fine until my pc shutting down suddenly. Now starting VS2013, then loading the solution, building the solution and starting the web application in debug mode, the output window lists a bunch of DLLs that get loaded and unloaded. When I run my application in IIS express it loads forever in browser. No errors. Here is output windows:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\d96b1297\15b7cae3_0ec8cf01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\d8ac4f40\15b7cae3_0ec8cf01\System.Web.WebPages.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\66ca740a\7b7d3c0a_e690d001\Nop.Core.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\822fa4ed\61ebfce3_0ec8cf01\System.Web.Mvc.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\c83b50fa\0590cae3_0ec8cf01\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\915c0ef4\17ecec75_f595cf01\WebActivator.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\322c44b1\7a1c9475_f595cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\f544634e\f49e564f_0ec9cf01\Autofac.Integration.Mvc.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime\v4.0_12.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.HadSpentAmount.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\a075dbfa\10bf6016_e690d001\Nop.Web.Framework.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\1fa15e1c\d276fb0d_e690d001\Nop.Services.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Tax.FixedRate.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.SMS.Verizon.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Shipping.FixedRateShipping.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Payments.PurchaseOrder.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalDirect.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\PayPalCoreSDK.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\PayPalMerchantSDK.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\d84878df\338a2fa9_17f5cf01\FluentValidation.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Payments.KrediKarti.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\048a7e95\3cf11474_f595cf01\EntityFramework.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\45f1a83e\4b65360b_e690d001\Nop.Data.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\eda4d1c6\b66eda78_c7b7cf01\Autofac.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Payments.AuthorizeNet.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Misc.WebServices.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Misc.EuroMessage.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\EPPlus.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\ImageResizer.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\itextsharp.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\MaxMind.Db.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\MaxMind.GeoIP2.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\PerceptiveMCAPI.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\PerlRegex.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Recaptcha.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\System.Web.Helpers.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\System.Web.Razor.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\UserAgentStringLibrary.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.ExchangeRate.McExchange.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.HasOneProduct.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.GoogleAnalytics.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Mono.Math.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\Org.Mentalis.Security.Cryptography.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\899226b9\55ea3673_f595cf01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\daf63139\76dc0288_380dd001\AutoMapper.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\d107b4e1\76dc0288_380dd001\AutoMapper.Net4.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\6c7d90b3\61b51e74_f595cf01\EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\fa6281ae\d6b1f4a9_17f5cf01\FluentValidation.Mvc.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\ddf5719c\ffbb3774_f595cf01\ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\0227646e\f7cb25d7_3eb1cf01\MiniProfiler.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\b5c96e2c\866f3c1a_e690d001\Nop.Admin.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\ca5c9887\19991da6_12a1cf01\Nop.Services.XmlSerializers.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\0ba902b5\15fb861b_e690d001\Nop.Web.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\780b43a7\676efc4d_6106d001\RestSharp.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe\4.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\41acee30\950ba0e4_0ec8cf01\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\cd135497\53a630e4_0ec8cf01\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\43599724\a532a0e4_0ec8cf01\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\e057da06\a91550e4_0ec8cf01\System.Web.Http.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\abf1192f\b2bc67e4_0ec8cf01\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\assembly\dl3\c2918841\3084ef75_f595cf01\WebGrease.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\fe4d4298\a5916eb6\App_global.asax.t0honqj9.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130763716115812893): Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.resources.dll'
```

Now I have tried everything I could find on the net:

Removing all breakpoints in the project,
Loading symbols in a local cache directory (in Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols),
Repairng .NET Frameworks
and a few other solutions that did not work

The weird thing is other similar projects still working fine. Problem occuring on project which was open while PC unexpected shutdown.

I spent more than 2 day to solve the problem.

Comment: Try deleting all files from directory C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files. If your are not able to delete it then kill/close your IISExpress.exe process and then try deleting.

Comment: i've tried to delete all files. It didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is another process interfering here, perhaps due to the way the solution/project is configured. Here are a few things you could try - deleting the asp.net temporary cache, also try restarting your machine again. Then if it is still an issue, check to see if there are any running processes for iisexpress or asp.net development environment. Check the project properties to see that it is configured OK to run in iis express. Seems project/solution config specific if other projects are debugging OK. Make sure all debug processes are detached before debugging with a new debug instance. Check solution config properties. Also check your web config is similar to the other projects that work. It might also be worth checking that copylocal and specificversion properties of project references are set up OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to switch from IIS Express to normal IIS. It seems to avoid reloading all the other DLLs every time.

Additionally you can check, and maybe temporaly disable Antivirus, (Windows Defender, for example) that tries to scan the DLL files every time. Also, if you have 'only' 4GB RAM and think that you need more RAM memory, about 8GB or 16GB